# How overwrite chef solo @params in Vagrantfile using chef.json?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, provisioning

I'm trying to overwrite `@params[:allow_override]` from `web_app.conf.erb` from the apache2 cookbook, but after 2 hours of trying I'm giving up. Does anyone know how to do it?

Just want to say I would like to do it from inside Vagrantfile in the `chef.json` definition.

Answer (score 0):

web_app is a Chef definition, which means it's like a function that's invoked from a recipe to set up that web_app. You can set those parameters as attributes in your Vagrantfile and pass them in through the web_app invocation.